# NSDateFormatter - getObjectValue:forString:range:error: returns incorrect date

Tags: iphone

I am trying to convert from an NSString to NSDate using `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:`. The function returns success and no errors, but the returned date is incorrect.

Specifically, I am passing `@"1989-12-31T00:00:00+00:00"` to the function below and the returned date is `1970-01-01 00:00:000 +0000`.  Any thoughts?

```
+ (NSDate *) convertStringToDate:(NSString *) dateString
{
    NSDate* date = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length]);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    BOOL success = [dateFormatter getObjectValue:&date forString:dateString range:&range error:&error];
    [dateFormatter release];

    return success ? date : nil;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:locale];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[usLocale release];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Notes:

- Get locale for NSLocale init from source you're getting this date like RSS feed or similar.
- setDateFormate: adjust to format of your source.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  The issue with this solution is that (1) I cannot guarantee the format of the date (so i believe i have to use getObjectValue:forString:range:error:). (2)In the example that is  shown in the question, I would have to remove the last ":" in the dateString if I want to explicitly set the date format.  NSDateFormat seems not to expect the last ":".  This maybe a bug.

Comment: @Tolu Fapohunda Regarding 2. I think there is combination of modifiers that allows this. Documentation is not really straightforward so little experimentation is needed.